# how to insert a key with values into a specific place inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my example array

`$inputs = array();`

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "13.1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "13.2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "14.1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "14.2"
  }
}
```

During my foreach loop, I could be currently working with `$inputs[2]` and conditional logic would determine that immediately above this one a new array needs to be added.  Please see next example..

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "13.1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "13.2"
  }
```

---

```
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "NEW"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "NEW"
  }
```

---

```
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "14.1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "14.2"
  }
}
```

How would I do this?

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please try to clarify what you want to achieve, it's not clear to me.

Comment: @Nelson Hi I'm running through a foreach loop and a function is called to add an 'entry' above the current 'active' key.  I don't know how else to explain it.  I'd rather that is is inserted immediately above, rather than top or bottom to maintain ordering.

Comment: Is this like insertion sort? As in, do you only need to insert one item each time?

Comment: @Jack yes, just needs to be added at the time the function determines that it needs to happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array-splice):

```
$inputs = ... your original array;
$newElement = array(array('id' => 'NEW', 'name' => 'NEW'));
array_splice($inputs, 2, 0, $newElement);

var_dump($inputs); // your desired array :)
```

edit: fixed `$newElement` initialization, it must be an array containing your new elements, so it must be an array that contains the new element you want, a new array.

Comment: @Jack inside a `for` it should work. Inside a `foreach` I don't know, but I guess it won't because the internal pointer of the array may get modified by `array_splice`

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_splice in a simple for

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
    if (/* condition is true */) {
        array_splice($array, $i, 0, /* your new array */);
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a new `array`

try

```
$array = array(
        0 => array("id" => "1","name" => "13.1"),
        1 => array("id" => "2","name" => "13.2"),
        2 => array("id" => "3","name" => "14.1"),
        3 => array("id" => "4","name" => "14.2"));


$append = array("id" => "new","name" => "new");
$copy = array();
$id = 2 ; // add after this ID

foreach($array as $value)
{
    $copy[] = $value ;
    $id == $value['id'] AND $copy[] = $append ;

}

var_dump($copy);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string '13.1' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string '13.2' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string 'new' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'new' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string '14.1' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string '14.2' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function:

```
function insertIn($array, $position, $element)
{
    $output = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$position;$i++)
    {
         $output[$i] = $array[$i];
    }
    $output[$position] = $element;
    for($i=$position+1;$i<count($array)+1;$i++)
    {
         $output[$i] = $array[$i-1];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way:

```
$new_array= array_merge( array_slice($array, 0, $pos), array(($pos+1)=>$value), array_slice($array, $pos, count($array)-$pos) );
```

There might be a bug in there, but you get the idea ..